# What are the units used when Image is moved in Kotlin. Matrix.tranlate vs view.scrollby

Tags: matrix, scroll, imageview, translate

I need to know how the method used to move an Image in a ImageView is affected in terms of units. (px, dp, etc.)

For instance, when we do:

```
valueX = 10
valueY = 10
imageview.scrollBy((valueX, valueY)
```

///// scrollby is in px units according to the documentation

vs

```
valueX = 10
valueY = 10
m = imageView.imageMatrix
m.translate(valueX, valueY)
///// I can't find which units or unit factor is used
```